# How do I render a controller returned image in a Twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

In order to protect images uploaded by customers I store them in "app/data" and retrieve them by using the following controller:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

class AssetsController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function serveProfilePictureAction() {
        ...
        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/' . $this->getImageMimeType($filePath));
        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

The controller works fine and serves an image if I call it by using a route. But how do I embed the image in a Twig template? I tried

```
{{ render(controller('SecuredAssetsBundle:Assets:serveProfilePicture')) }}
```

but that doesn't do anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to embed it as an image tag for the browser to fetch for you:

```
<img src="{{ path('serveProfilePictureRoute') }}" alt="Your profile picture" />
```

Where `serveProfilePictureRoute` is whatever you've named your profile picture route.

Comment: Can't believe it's that simple especially when I have dozens of "path" calls in my Twig templates...

Thanks!